# JS strict mode enabling in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, strict

To enable strict mode in JavaScript it's needed to insert 'use strict' to a script.
If I have several scripts, I need to add it to all.
Maybe it can be added only once in settings?
Not found any examples for now.

P.S. I know about add-ons that add statement to all scripts, it's not very convenient anyway.

Comment: the editor (VSC) settings have nothing to do with running your JavaScript. Use a shell script to add the line to all files, you can filter based on the content of line 1, `grep` and `head -1`

Comment: Does using `"alwaysStrict": true,` in your `jsconfig.json` work for you?

Answer (score 3):

> To enable strict mode in JavaScript it's needed to insert 'use strict' to a script.

**Or** to use modules, which are strict by default. To tell the JavaScript parser (and VS Code) that a file is a module, add an `import` or `export` to it. You can have an empty `export` if the file is completely standalone:

```
export {}
```

...although usually, once you adopt modules, you just naturally end up with `import` and `export` to share functions and such between the modules, so you don't need something synthetic like that (or `"use strict";`).

Modules offer benefits beyond automatically being in strict mode, such as having their own top-level scope (rather than top-level code being in global scope) and, of course, declarative dependencies between files.

More about modules [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and in Chapter 13 of my recent book [*JavaScript: The New Toys*](https://thenewtoys.dev).

> Maybe it can be added only once in settings?

The problem with doing that is that VS Code's settings have no effect on the JavaScript engine that will ultimately be responsible for parsing and evaluating the code. That's why you need something in the file itself.